# Changing UIScrollView Paging Sensitivity

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Anyone here happen to know how I might go about making a UIScrollView paging less sensitive?

I am only scrolling left or right, but if I scroll a single pixel in the horizontal direction, the UIScrollView rockets off to the next page. I understand that the paging property stops on multiples of the scrollview's bounds, and that's totally fine. I just don't want this to happen unless it's abundantly clear the user wants to do this.

Can this be done using the native functionality of UIScrollView or will I have to override touch events and code this myself?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: UIScrollView shouldn't be rocketing to the next page if you scroll a single pixel. You need to break past at least the third or even half to have it snap to the next page. I'm not sure what's causing the behavior you're describing...